# publish menu item missing in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, winforms

I have created a .Net Framework based Windows APP using Windows Forms. I got the application working and I can run the .exe generated in my development folder on the system that I developed it on. However, when I copy the .exe to another windows PC (same ver), I get DLL errors. It seems like I need to publish the app. Unfortunately, the menu that appears when I right click on the project in Solution Explorer, is missing the publish option. After "Analyze and Code cleanup", I see "Project only". Also, the "Deploy" button under Solution project properties is greyed out.

I have looked around everywhere but can't find publish option. Does it require MSDN subscription or something else? What am I missing? I did log in to my live.com account.

I have lot of Linux development experience but not much on Windows so appreciate gentle suggestions!

Comment: You way another Windows PC "same ver". What do you mean, like version 10? Biggest thing is if 1) the target machine has same version of .NET runtime, 2) there are any third party components you are using that are present on one machine and not the other. Use ProcMon on the other PC to see what registry entries of files it is not finding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both are fully up-to-date Windows10 PCs. Also I used CLR .NET Framework so it should in theory interoperate right? I will check the .NET versions and maybe try a different PC but the real question I have is why my "Publish" option is missing?

Comment: @SBuch, it seems that it is visual studio design problem. First, please try to update your vs to the latest version. Second, if this can not help you to solve the problem, please report a problem in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/search?space=8).

Comment: Thanks @JackJJun-MSFT Yes - seems so - I have reported: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Publish-option-missing-in-VS2019-1694/1398470

Comment: It seems Microsoft has not assigned anyone to work on this yet. If you are running into this issue, please upvote the above developer community link. Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem. I discovered, that I did not install the ClickOnce publishing option with Visual Studio, but added this since. However I can still not find the "Publish" menu item

Comment: Did Microsoft ever fix this problem ? I am having the same issue now on ver 16.11.2

Comment: Have you created new publish profiles for each environment in your Visual Studio?